# How do I write this code using loops (It's a Tic Tac Toe code - determining the winner of a game by returning their character)

Tags: python, loops, tic-tac-toe

The code is below, it should return the value of the symbol that one the game, exclude the " " spaces. I'm trying to shorten it but I'm new to coding so having a hard time.

The board you input its int the following format: [["X", " ", "O"], ["O", "X", " "], ["O", " ", "X"]]

```
def winner(board):

    term00 = board[0][0]
    term01 = board[0][1]
    term02 = board[0][2]
    term10 = board[1][0]
    term11 = board[1][1]
    term12 = board[1][2]
    term20 = board[2][0]
    term21 = board[2][1]
    term22 = board[2][2]


    if term00 == term01 == term02:
        if term00 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term00
    elif term00 == term10 == term20:
        if term00 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term00
    elif term02 == term12 == term22:
        if term02 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term02
    elif term20 == term21 == term22:
        if term20 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term20
    elif term00 == term11 == term22:
        if term00 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term00
    elif term02 == term11 == term20:
        if term00 == " ":
            pass
        else:
            return term00

    return None
```

Comment: Not sure how I already got a down voted lmao - but sorry if this is a poorly worded question.

Comment: Try "python tic-tac-toe" in your favorite search engine. You'll find plenty of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to the more functional aspects of Python, you'll see how it generally leads to more concise code. For example:

```python
def winner(board): 
    for player in ["X", "O"]:  
        # Rows
        res  = any(all(col == player for col in row) for row in board)  
        # Columns
        res |= any(all(row == player for row in col) for col in zip(*board)) 
        # Main diagonal
        res |= all(row[i] == player for i, row in enumerate(board))  
        # Secondary diagonal
        res |= all(row[~i] == player for i, row in enumerate(board)) 
        if res: 
            return player 
    return None
```